# Update from CTE does not update properly all table rows. But updates all existing table rows with CTE values returned in the first ID in CTE resultset

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

I've buit a CTE and want to update an existing physical table based on results from the CTE.

```
;WITH CTE
 AS 
 (
 Select t.ID As [CTE_ID]
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department='M' then t.ID else null end) as M_Marketing
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department='S' then t.ID else null end) as S_Sales   
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department='U' then t.ID else null end) as U_Utilization    
       ,count(distinct case when e.Department=' ' then t.ID else null end) as No_NoDepartment
    From dbo.Table t (nolock) 
        Left Join dbo.ClearedEmployee ce (nolock) ON t.ID = ce.building_fk
             Join dbo.Employee e (nolock) ON ce.employee_fk = e.employee_pk
    Group By t.ID
)

Select *,  t.ID 
From CTE c (nolock)
FULL JOIN dbo.Table t (nolock) ON t.ID=c.[CTE_ID]
Order By t.ID ASC;
```

I want to updated my existing table with the results produced BY THE CODE ABOVE for each ID within the CTE  And I'm using the code below:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table t
    SET Marketing=M_Marketing,
        Sales=S_Sales, 
        Utilization=U_Utilization,
        NoDepartment=No_NoDepartment
    FROM CTE
```

But this code updates all rows (all rows with unique IDs) of Marketing, Sales, Utilization and NoDepartment columns with values that present in the first row of the CTE result set. Basicaly I cannot really use CTE true result set to update the table.

Comment: Please, fix the title. The CAPS LOCK is unbearable to read.

Comment: Please edit the title to remove the SHOUTING. It's not necessary to SHOUT at us here. We can all read quite well. SHOUTING will not get you help any faster, it's extremely rude and annoying, and it's more difficult to read. Please stop SHOUTING now. It appeared at first you were having difficulties with your keyboard, and I was going to start asking for donations to buy you a new one, but it apparently works fine in the body of your post, so it's just you being RUDE by SHOUTING at us. Please {edit] to fix that issue; we don't like SHOUTING here.

Comment: @Ken, in the time it took you to write that essay, you probably could have solved the issue. But it wouldn't have been as funny, so kudos for that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yeah, I could have fixed it, but then the poster doesn't learn, and keeps SHOUTING all his questions like the little boy in the playground trying to get your attention. The poster needs to learn that we don't SHOUT HERE, and that SHOUTING here has concequences like downvotes until the problem is remedied, and hopefully no help until the question is more clearly written either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  t
    SET t.Marketing=M_Marketing,
        t.Sales=S_Sales, 
        t.Utilization=U_Utilization,
        t.NoDepartment=No_NoDepartment
    FROM CTE C JOIN Table T ON T.ID=C.CTE_ID
```

In your update statement, you need to tell SQL Server how to map the data from the CTE to the data from the table.

Comment: Thank you Akash. I appreciate your tips.